# Simple producer-consumer collection without BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, multithreading, producer-consumer

I want to write a simple producer-consumer queue, without using the built-in `System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection`. Here's a quick attempt that "seems" to work. Is there anything wrong with it threading-wise,  race conditions, deadlocks etc.?

```
class ProducerConsumerQueue<T>
{
    Queue<T> Queue = new Queue<T>();
    ManualResetEvent Event = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    object Lock = new object();

    public void Add(T t)
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            Queue.Enqueue(t);
        }
        Event.Set();
    }

    public bool TryTake(out T t, int timeout)
    {
        if (Event.WaitOne(timeout))
        {
            lock (Lock)
            {
                if (Queue.Count > 0)
                {
                    t = Queue.Dequeue();
                    if (Queue.Count == 0) Event.Reset();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        t = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Btw. the only two methods I need are `Add` and `TryTake`, I don't need `IEnumerable`  etc.

Comment: why not to use better implementations(better performance without deadlocks) like `ConcurrentQueue` ?

Comment: @ibubi I need timeout when removing items from queue, ConcurrentQueue does not have that.

Comment: This is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You want a blocking Queue with a TryTake method in which you can pass a timeout?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü Yes

Comment: @kaalus, then how about changing  `Queue<T> Queue = new Queue<T>();` into `ConcurrentQueue` so that you get rid of `Lock` then instead of ManualResetEvent, into `Semaphoreslim`. Other than that it looks like what you have is working

Comment: @kaalus, It is just a hunch but are you somehow trying to replicate golang`s channel feature?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü No, sorry, I'm not trying to replicate anything in golang.

Comment: ​The [`BlockingCollection<T>.TryTake`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.trytake) method has an optional `timeout` parameter, and is available from .NET Framework 4.0 onwards. Why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft recently dropped `System.Threading.Channels`, which is intended to provide optimized producer/consumer APIs, which may be a good fit in this case. It covers unbounded and bounded scenarios, and includes single plus multiple reader/writer scenarios. The API is pretty simple and intuitive to use; the only slight caveat is that it uses an `async`-orientated API (for the consumer, and - in the case of bounded channels - for the producer).

The point here being: the code you don't write tends to be code that has fewer pain points - especially if it was written by a team with expertise and interest in the specific problems being targeted.

---

However: you can do everything in your current code without needing the `ManualResetEvent` - `lock` in C# is just a wrapper around the *simplest* parts of `Monitor`, but `Monitor` also provides wait/pulse functionality:

```
class ProducerConsumerQueue<T>
{
    private readonly Queue<T> Queue = new Queue<T>();

    public void Add(T t)
    {
        lock (Queue)
        {
            Queue.Enqueue(t);
            if (Queue.Count == 1)
            {
                // wake up one sleeper
                Monitor.Pulse(Queue);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool TryTake(out T t, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        lock (Queue)
        {
            if (Queue.Count == 0)
            {
                // try and wait for arrival
                Monitor.Wait(Queue, millisecondsTimeout);
            }
            if (Queue.Count != 0)
            {
                t = Queue.Dequeue();
                return true;
            }
        }
        t = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. I've been analyzing your code, and I don't fully understand one thing. AFAIK Monitor.Pulse does not have internal state, therefore if no one is waiting on the monitor, the pulse will not wake up a reader and the first item in the queue will never be retrieved. Actually another thing is, if someone is waiting on the monitor in TryTake, he's holding a Queue lock, therefore no one can pulse the monitor in Add, which is in the same lock. Please let me know if I get this wrong.

Comment: @kaalus, there is a time out on Monitor.Wait. if nobody pulses it will fail to acquire the lock then continie

Comment: @kaalus when you call `Wait`, it puts the current thread into the pending queue for that monitor, and *releases* the lock for the duration of the wait; when the `Wait` completes (either by pulse or by timeout), the thread *re-acquires* the lock. So; `Wait` is a temporary surrender of the lock, with a pulse/timeout mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I think using both `lock` and a `ManualResetEvent` is redundant. I suggest you read more about [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=netframework-4.7.2) on how to enter and exit synchronized areas in your code (you can also take a look at other synchronization mechanisms available under [System.Threading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

If it's not just for exercise, you can also take a look at [NetMQ](https://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Good, though if OP isn't going to use first-class `BlockingCollection` he probably isn't going to use a 3rd party solution like NetMQ

Answer (score -1):

As per my comment in the question,

Here is a my proposed solution.

```
public class BlockingQueue<T>
{
    // In order to get rid of Lock object
    // Any thread should be able to add items to the queue
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<T> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();

    // Only one thread is able to consume from queue
    // You can fine tune this to your interest
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _slim = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);

    public void Add(T item) {
        _queue.Enqueue(item);
    }

    public bool TryTake(out T item, TimeSpan timeout) {
        if (_slim.Wait(timeout)){
            return _queue.TryDequeue(out item);
        }
        item = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the downvoter, I am more than happy to fix any mistakes if you tell me the problem :) thanks a lot

Comment: The `SemaphoreSlim` is never released. The `Add` method does not awake a waiting consumer. The `SemaphoreSlim` is a sufficient mechanism to use for this purpose, but it is not used correctly in the above code.